# abort() hanging indefinitely

Tags: c++, g++

The code (my original code used `assert`, but this is an even shorter [sscce](http://www.sscce.org/))

```
#include <cstdlib>

int main() {
    abort();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler version:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Compiled with:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test
```

Runtime:

```
$ ./test
```

Hangs indefinitely.  Checking `top` I notice `abrt-hook-ccpp` (as root) taking a whole CPU (pegged at 75%, with ./test taking 25%).

Other notes: this behaviour appears to be flaky, happening only about 80% of the time.  I tried at each level of optimization (O0 through O4) and had no differences.

Additionally I cannot reproduce this behaviour on my local machine (g++ 4.8.1)

Comment: use strace and pstack to check what your application is hanging to.

Comment: Trying to create a core file on some slow medium (like a dead NFS server), perhaps?

Comment: Use gdb to see what happens. See if SIGABRT is at all emitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably a bug in Redhat's Automatic Bug Reporting Tool. Try disabling the ABRT service and see if it works.

You can either disable abrt-ccpp:

```
# chkconfig abrt-ccpp off
# service abrt-ccpp stop
```

Or the whole service:

```
# chkconfig abrtd off
# service abrtd stop
```

Comment: If this is correct, it smacks of a bug in the ABRT service; it should give up after only a few seconds (like 1-2).